# Как создать кнопку на openGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

Интересует способ создания кнопки, например, как лучше это сделать.
Нужно, чтоб при наведении она меняла цвет, а при нажатии происходило какое-либо событие.
Например, у нас есть нарисованный квадрат (glRect), и него нужно повесить событие наведение на объект и клик на объект.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[@Александр Старцев](/users/27385/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2), рекомендую для начала разобраться, как устроен конвейер OpenGL.

Видеокарта не знает ничего ни о каких кнопках и тем более событиях. И почти не знает о квадратах. OpenGL главным образом занимается тем, что скармливает видеокарте списки координат вершин и дополнительные сведения о том, как их нарисовать. Т.е. все, что вам в данном случае позволяет библиотека это почистить экран и нарисовать квадрат. Дальше сами.

Заведите себе класс или структуру, описывающие кнопку: координаты, габариты и состояние кнопки (нажата/не нажата). Создайте экземпляр, заполните все поля. В цикле отрисовки чистите экран и выводите кнопку на основе вышеописанных данных.

Перехватите событие нажатия кнопки мыши. Если речь о Windows - через сообщение `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, например. Затем проверьте, попадает ли клик по вашей кнопке, сравнив координаты клика с координатами и размерами кнопки. Если - да измените состояние на "нажато". А по событию `WM_LBUTTONUP` аналогично проверьте и измените состояние на "не нажато". В это время обновлением внешнего вида будет усердно заниматься цикл отрисовки.

PS. Можете пойти скучным путем и взять готовую библиотеку, которая сделает все это за вас (есть варианты с рисованием интерфейса на Flash, например). Гуглить по ключевым словам "opengl ui framework".

Comment: Хотел бы я так легко, я бы сюда не написал, да и не писал на OpenGL

Comment: @Александр Старцев, если что-то не понятно - задавайте уточняющие вопросы, помогу разобраться. Таки мой диплом был посвящен рисованию окошек и кнопочек на OpenGL в С++ под Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Если это виндовс приложение, то мышь постоянно отправляет свои координаты и состояния кнопок как сообщения в очередь приложения. Думаю, вам не составит труда перехватить эти сообщения и наложить их на координаты вашего прямоугольника.

Answer (score 0):

На C++ нужно делать так:

Создается абстрактный класс с обработчиком события, а от него наследованием создаются классы графических объектов. OpenGL передает сообщение тому обработчику, объект которого находится в текущих координатах мыши. Назначать передачу сообщений можно и по другим событиям. События лучше отправлять в формате винды, чтобы потом не морочиться с несовместимостью.